# Word 2010 process background freeze

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2010

Sometimes when I close Word documents winword.exe still runs in background (but there's no document open) and when I then want to open a word file nothing happens. I first have to open Task Manager, stop the winword.exe process and then I can open another document.

I'm working on Windows 7 Professional 64 bit (Service Pack 1) with Office Word 2010 Home & Student.

Until now I couldn't figure out any pattern after which actions it happens. I already reinstalled Word with no difference. The Office Suite is up to date.

Comment: Are the documents you're working with (or your user profile) located somewhere else on a network?

Comment: Oh yes, the documents are on another PC running on Windows XP with a shared partition. I don't know exactly which user profile you mean?

Comment: Sometimes in a corporate network the My Documents (etc.) in the (your) user profile are redirected to a server, and sometimes Word likes to use this as its temporary space.

Answer (score 2):

Disable plugins attached to your Office installation, like antivirus, PDF writers or toolbars.

Try to open Word and while double clicking in the icon push and hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key until is done loading. This loads in diagnosis mode and no plugings are loaded.

From: [Enable or disable add-ins in Office programs - Support - Office.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/enable-or-disable-add-ins-in-office-programs-HA010034127.aspx#BM16)

> #### Word
>
> 1. Click the Microsoft Office Button , click Word Options, and then click Add-Ins.
> 2. In the Add-ins box, identify the add-in that you want to enable or disable and note the Add-in type located in the Type column.
> 3. Select the Add-in type in the Manage box and then click Go.
> 4. Select or clear the check box for the Add-in that you want enable or disable and then click OK.
>
> Note   Add-ins of type Document Inspector are enabled using a different method. These add-ins are automatically enabled when you inspect the document for hidden
> metadata or personal information. To inspect your document, click the
> Microsoft Office Button , click Prepare, and then click Inspect
> Document.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that if you just ignored it for a little bit, it would eventually close on it's own.

Having files being read and written over the network can cause delay.

With network idle time-outs and such, if you're working on a document for while then it may take Word a while to close up, as it may need to wake up network connections to ensure all of it's (remote) resources are cleaned up properly before ending the process.

Additional plug-ins like anti-virus and such, as Jaun Carlos pointed out, can exacerbate this.

The same things happen with local files and resources as well, it's just that introducing a network brings a large amount of noticeable overhead and therefore takes longer to finalize things.